# How to set image in Aspect fit on Texture2D in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture2d

Hi I am new bee in Unity and I am working on an app in which i want to load my Images in Aspect fit ratio on Texture. I Know that i can achieve this using ScaleMode.ScaleToFit but i am not getting this property in Texture 2d. I am doing following like this.

```
Texture2D tex = Resources.Load("ImageTargetTextures/WhatTheBuck/MYPicture") as Texture2D; 
video.mIconPlane.renderer.material.mainTexture = tex; 
video.mIconPlane.transform.rotation=Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, Vector3.up); 
video.mIconPlane.transform.localScale = ScaleMode.ScaleToFit;
```

Video is the Object of my VideoClass and mIconPlane is public Game Object in Video Class. This will be great for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a size of your image in pixels from one of public properties of `Texture2D` class (can tell what exactly at the moment). Then, just set `new Vector3 (textureWidth/someValue, textureHeigth/someValue,1)` to `video.mIconPlane.transform.localScale`. `someValue` - is some number to make your GameObject's size as you whant. It depends on `Camera` size.